# Syntax error near '.`value)` != '') in 5.1.73

Tags: mysql

Is the following sql statement is supported in mysql 5.1.73?

error:

> ```
> Syntax error near '.`value)` != '') AND (`IF(address`.`value IS NULL,
> main_table`.`address, address' at line 4
> ```

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `storepickup_store` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `storepickup_store_value` AS `status` ON main_table.store_id = status.storepickup_id AND status.store_id = 4 AND status.attribute_code = 'status'
 LEFT JOIN `storepickup_store_value` AS `city` ON main_table.store_id = city.storepickup_id AND city.store_id = 4 AND city.attribute_code = 'city'
 LEFT JOIN `storepickup_store_value` AS `address` ON main_table.store_id = address.storepickup_id AND address.store_id = 4 AND address.attribute_code = 'address' 
WHERE (`IF(status`.`value IS NULL, main_table`.`status, status`.`value)` = '1') 
  AND (`IF(city`.`value IS NULL, main_table`.`city, city`.`value)` != '') 
  AND (`IF(address`.`value IS NULL, main_table`.`address, address`.`value)` != '') 
  AND (`zipcode` != '') 
ORDER BY store_name ASC
```

Comment: Check backtick places. In your case you may remove ALL backticks - no point where they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
`IF(status`.`value IS NULL, main_table`.`status, status`.`value)`
```

should be replaced by

```
IF(`status`.`value` IS NULL, `main_table`.`status`, `status`.`value`)
```

But, as stated by Akina you should rid of all that backticks. Backticks are necessary only if you want to use some reserved word as identifier like `TIME` or `DATE`. In all other cases backticks are redundant and only obfuscate the code.

Comment: *Backticks are necessary only if you want to use some reserved word as identifier like TIME or DATE.* ... or in case of identifier contains a char which can be interpreted as a service one. For example, a space or a bracket.

Comment: @Akina In common in every case of ambiguity that can confuse the parser.

Comment: We do not know the "interior kitchen" of a parser, so may be some situations when it will not be confused, but the result will be wrong... for example, in case of double non-obviousness.

Comment: @Akina It would be very interesting to see an example that produce the wrong result instead of `SYNTAX ERROR` from the parser.

Comment: Synthetic example. ``create table a (y,z,`x(y`,`z)`);`` `create function x(m,n);` `select x(y,z) from a;` ``select `x(y`,`z)` from a;``

Comment: @Akina Great example.